# Android Device Manage throws error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-emulator

Whenever I try to create a new virtual device in Android Device Manager from Visual Studio, I get the following error:

```
AVD CREATION ERROR: AVD failed to create with error : AVD Manager has returned non-zero exit code: 1. Please check logs for more information.
```

From `logs`, I found the following snippet which is probably the error:

```
[18-05-12 10:45:44.76] [AvdManager.CreateAvd] AVD Manager has returned non-zero exit code: 1
Command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\avdmanager.batcreate avd -n my_device -k system-images;android-25;google_apis_playstore;x86 --tag google_apis_playstore --abi x86 -d Nexus 5X --sdcard 100M
Details: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 5 more
```

It happens no matter whatever configuration or version of Android I use.

Details:
OS: Windows 10 Professional x64
Processor: Ryzen 1700

Comment: Read [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187076/xamarin-android-device-manager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling all other versions of JAVA SDK except SDK 8 done the work for me.

My current JAVA SDK's:

[image]